# Second layout is not showing with include tag in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I have designed two Android layouts which should be shown in order. So, the first layout must be showing in top of the page and the second layout must be showing in bottom of the page. However, the following code only shows the first layout. How can I show the second layout too?

the main layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/first_layout"/>
    <include layout="@layout/second_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The first xml layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.simplifiedcoding.androidloginapp.UserProfile">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The second layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"       
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"      
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextName" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Address"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextAddress" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Insert"
    android:onClick="insert"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewResult" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in the preview how much space on the screen does the main and 1st layout take?

Comment: Show the Java code you are using to show the first layout

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not yet sure if this will solve your problem, but can you try adding `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` in your included layout as well as layout weight?

```
<include layout="@layout/first_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<include layout="@layout/second_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

**Added info**

The reason why you have that problem is because both your layouts uses `match_parent` for the height. That means that at the first layout, it will match the size of the parent (which in this case is the whole screen), thus, the first layout will occupy the whole screen and the second layout won't appear.

In this solution, you are telling both layouts to consume only half of the screen by using the `layout_weight`.

Comment: Yes it is working but can you add some explanation how it is solved?

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi btw, have you tried codeMagic's solution? I want to know if that will work.

Comment: I am too now that it was downvoted :/ But I don't see what's wrong about it

Comment: @codeMagic I will try it later, if your solution works I will upvote you. haha

Comment: i just changed android:layout_height as you said but it did not work

Comment: why are you using `android:layout_weight` attribute 2 times?

Comment: This definitely works. If it does not work for you, you have a different layout composition. As I can't give a hint for every composition possible, I'll just recommend to try out giving these attributes to the different layouts, until things match. In my case, there is a single include inside a LinearLayout. That includes a layout having a NavigationView. I need this, so I can display a menu item inside a DrawerLayout inside a NavigationView with bottom gravity.

Answer (score 10):

In your first layout, you have

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

so it is taking up the entire height of your main layout. Change that to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and you should be good.

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

> The root View should be exactly how you'd like it to appear in each layout to which you add this layout.

Note that

> You can also override all the layout parameters (any `android:layout_*` attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the `<include/>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should use RelativeLayout on your main layout. If you use LinearLayout one item will always be shown bellow the previous element and since both yours layout are match_parent the second won't be shown.