# Copy an android program and paste to another android program makes error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have developed a program which works in android studio.
Theare are three components of this program:
MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml and list_item.xml as following

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String myJSON;

private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_ADD ="address";

JSONArray peoples = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    getData();
}


protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
            persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
            persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);

            personList.add(persons);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mowena.com/userregistration/amir.php");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

activity_main.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"      
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I wanted to use this program as a third layout in [Second layout is not showing with include tag in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544880/second-layout-is-not-showing-with-include-tag-in-android-studio). Therefore, I have copied and pasted this program. Then, I have changed the names of java program MainActivity.java to Main2Activity.java and changes some parameters of this program as following:

Main2Activity.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Main2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

String myJSON;

private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_ADD ="address";

JSONArray peoples = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    getData();
}


protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
            persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
            persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);

            personList.add(persons);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Main2Activity.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mowena.com/userregistration/amir.php");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

However, it gives me the following error:
[image]

activity_user_profile.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<include layout="@layout/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

first_layout.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="net.simplifiedcoding.androidloginapp.UserProfile">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

second_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextName" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Comment"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextAddress" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Insert"
    android:onClick="insert"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewResult" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<include layout="@layout/first_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<include layout="@layout/second_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<include layout="@layout/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

package com.example.alan.mainactivity;

```
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText editTextUserName;
private EditText editTextPassword;

public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

String username;
String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
}

public void invokeLogin(View view){
    username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

    login(username,password);

}

private void login(final String username, String password) {

    class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String uname = params[0];
            String pass = params[1];

            InputStream is = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
            String result = null;

            try{
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://www.oobac.com/app/login.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String s = result.trim();
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("alan")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
    la.execute(username, password);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Is anyone can help?

Here is my Logcat:

```
 com.example.alan.mainactivity E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.alan.mainactivity, PID: 23490
            Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {
                com.example.alan.mainactivity / com.example.alan.mainactivity.UserProfile
            }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
            on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 616)
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
            on a null object reference
            at com.example.alan.mainactivity.UserProfile.onCreate(UserProfile.java: 23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 616)
            com.example.alan.mainactivity I / Process: Sending signal.PID: 23490 SIG: 9
```

Comment: By the logs it seems.You have a activity named UserProfile. You have a textView in it which is null and you are calling setText on it. Where is code of UserProfile class?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Here is UserProfile

Answer (score 0):

There is no textView in your user profile layout file with id = R.id.textView3

change this line

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

to

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Comment: When I have run activity_main.xml and MainActivity.java and list_item.xml as a single project it is working

Answer (score 0):

activity_user_profile.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/first_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<include layout="@layout/second_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<include layout="@layout/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am using textView3 in first_layout.xml as <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

Comment: but you are not settting first_layout.xml to setContentView in UserProfile class. You are setting activity_user_profile.xml which doesnot have textView3

Comment: you know I am going to show three layout respectively in a signal layout. first_layout.xml , second_layout.xml and list_item.xml must be show in single layout

Comment: I had MainActivity.java before. Therefore, I changed the name of new code to Main2Activity but it does not work

Comment: Firstly error is not coming in MainActivity or Main2Activity. It is coming in UserProfile. And reason is its not able to find textview. So you said you want to display 3 layout first_layout.xml , second_layout.xml and list_item.xml in same activity? Is this activity UserProfile?

Comment: Dear I am a beginner. I just copy and past tree codes and want to make an application based on them. When I have used the list_item.xml and Main2Activity.java, an error is happening. If it is possible for you, explain more for me. Thank you

Comment: I have update the question. Please regard it. Thanks.

Comment: Difficult to understand. But from what i understood i think you should cut 2nd linearlayout from second_layout.xml and paste in activity_user_profile.xml. Check the way i created activity_user_profile.xml.

Comment: you mean I should copy  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content" into second_layout.xml? do you have any email to send you the project ?