# RecyclerView does not show any items when included

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a Recycler view with the code below, which is working perfectly with all items when the view is accessed directly, but when it is included the RecyclerView is visible but empty

RecyclerView View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
 />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Parent View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/list_fragment" />

<include layout="@layout/controls_fragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my list fragment onCreateView function I also have the below code

```
    val context = requireContext()
    binding.listItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    val listItemAdapter = ListItemAdapter(context, items)
    binding.listItems.adapter = listItemAdapter
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544880/second-layout-is-not-showing-with-include-tag-in-android-studio

Comment: No, that is a different issue all-together

Answer (score 1):

The issues is fixed by using "fragment" instead of "include" in the Parent View.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500sp"
    android:name="com.example.project.listFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/list_fragment">
</fragment>


<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200sp"
    android:id="@+id/controlsFragment"
    android:name="com.example.project.ControlsFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/controls_fragment">
</fragment>
```